# what is ultimate root of visible UIView hierarchy tree?

Tags: ios, uiview

what is ultimate root of visble `UIView` hierarchy tree? 
Is that one of `UIWindow` object that can retrieve by `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]`? is that true so for modal `UIView`?

Comment: Yes. Every App consists of MainWindow.xib file. That's the parent of all. If using newer versions of Xcode, A UIWindow will be declared at the start in the AppDelegate's didFinishWithLaunching method.

Comment: Yes, modal UIViewController would be added to a Parent UIViewController which is again added on UIWindow

Comment: make it as an answer, i will accept

Comment: @mayuur Provided you use Interface Builder, that is. I would say that every app has one instance of UIWindow made key and visible on launch.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Correct. Every app should have atleast one UIWindow according to Apple iOS Documentation and every UIView added on this Window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Every App consists of MainWindow.xib file. That's the parent of all. If using newer versions of Xcode, A UIWindow will be declared at the start in the AppDelegate's didFinishWithLaunching method.

Also, Modal UIViewController would be added to a Parent UIViewController which is again added on UIWindow